# Add a text field in MUI Autocomplete options dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add an editable **text field** in dropdown options of MUI Autocomplete.
I was able to add MUI **text field** by adding it in `renderOption` prop of Autocomplete.

[image]

**Problem**
I am not able to edit the text fields since the autocomplete selection overrides it.

```
<Autocomplete
        open={open}
        multiple
        value={!!value ? [value] : []}
        classes={{ popupIndicatorOpen: classes.popupOpen }}
        closeIcon={null}
        popupIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon style={{ opacity: 0.6 }}/>}
        forcePopupIcon
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        options={options} //array            
        getOptionLabel={opt => isInstanceOfIRange(opt) ? Concatenate([opt.min.value, opt.max.value], ' - ') : opt.value.toString() || ''}
        renderTags={(opts, getTagProps) =>
          opts.map((opt, index) => (
            <CustomTag key={index.toString()} opt={opt} {...getTagProps({ index })} classes={classes} />) 
          )}
       
        onChange={handleChange}/
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label={props.label}
            variant='filled'
            onFocus={() => setOpen(true)}
            onInput={onInputChange}
          />
        )}
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
          <CustomOption option={option} selected={selected} />
        )}
        PopperComponent={PopperComponent}
        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
      />
```

**Custom Options rendering text box**

```
  const CustomOption = ({ selected, option }) => (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Checkbox
           size="small"
           color="primary"
           checked={selected}
           style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
           icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
           checkedIcon={<RadioButtonCheckedIcon />}
           />
          {
          isInstanceOfIRange(option) ? <RangeRender option={option} /> : <SingleRender 
          option={option} />
          }
         </div>
          );
```

**The Two text boxes are rendered using this component**

```
const RangeRender = ({ option: { min, max } }) => {
      const { labelPostfix, labelPrefix } = useContext(DropDownContext);
      const inputProps = labelPrefix ? {
      startAdornment:  <InputAdornment position="start">{labelPrefix}</InputAdornment>,
      } : labelPostfix ? { endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">{labelPostfix} 
      </InputAdornment>,} : {};

     return (
   <Box style={{ display: 'flex', gap: 12 }}>
  <NummberField
    type="number"
    variant="outlined"
    value={min.value}
    InputProps={inputProps}
  />
  <NummberField
    type="number"
    variant="outlined"
    value={max.value}
    InputProps={inputProps}
  />
</Box>);
```

};

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: Here is a sandbox which demonstrates the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-mui-forked-c6stt8?file=%2Findex.js%3A14%2C26